# syslog-ng filter log by frequency to destination file

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, syslog-ng

I have a syslog-ng that receives too many logs and I am trying a way to 'sample' them using some filter.
I assume editing the /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf with something like
log { source(s_udp514); filter(every XXmin); destination(d_udp514); };

Where filter(every 15min) will write only on XXmin to destination. Do you know how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `modulate()` filter allows you to specify a time interval and only allows messages to pass through at specific intervals.

*EXAMPLE:*

```
source s_udp514 {
    # Your source configuration here
};

filter f_modulate {
    modulate(interval 15m);
};

destination d_udp514 {
    # Your destination configuration here
};

log {
    source(s_udp514);
    filter(f_modulate);
    destination(d_udp514);
};
```

In this example, the `modulate()` filter is configured with a 15m interval. The log statement uses the `s_udp514 source`, applies the `f_modulate` filter, and sends the filtered messages to the `d_udp514` destination.

Comment: `modulate()` doesn't seem to be available in syslog-ng. Can you show any reference?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar can be achieved by filtering based on the value of time macros, such as `${R_MIN}`, `${R_HOUR}`, or `${R_UNIXTIME}`.